# Cannot compile xmonad.hs file

Tags: haskell, archlinux, window-managers, xmonad

I am using xmonad on top of an arch based system. But after upgrading i am not able to compile my xmonad.hs file via

`$ xmonad --recompile`

I seem to be getting error on every module of xmonad, even import XMonad doesn't seem to work. 
If anyone has fixed this issue somehow please let me know.

#### Error Messages:

```
Error detected while loading xmonad configuration file: 
/home/arya/.xmonad/xmonad.hs

xmonad.hs:2:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
2 | import XMonad
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:3:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Config.Mate’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
3 | import XMonad.Config.Mate
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:5:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.StackSet’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
5 | import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:8:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
8 | import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:9:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
9 | import XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:10:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Layout.Minimize’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
10 | import XMonad.Layout.Minimize
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Please check the file for errors.

[arya@localhost ~]$ Warning: Missing charsets in String to FontSet 
conversion
[arya@localhost ~]$ 
monad.hs:9:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
9 | import XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:10:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Layout.Minimize’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
10 | import XMonad.Layout.Minimize
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

#### Output:

`$ type -a ghc`

```
ghc is /usr/local/bin/ghc
ghc is /usr/bin/ghc
```

Output of
`$  ghc-pkg list`
:

```
 /usr/local/haskell/ghc-8.2.2-x86_64/lib/ghc-8.2.2/package.conf.d
    Cabal-2.0.1.0
    array-0.5.2.0
    base-4.10.1.0
    binary-0.8.5.1
    bytestring-0.10.8.2
    containers-0.5.10.2
    deepseq-1.4.3.0
    directory-1.3.0.2
    filepath-1.4.1.2
    (ghc-8.2.2)
    ghc-boot-8.2.2
    ghc-boot-th-8.2.2
    ghc-compact-0.1.0.0
    ghc-prim-0.5.1.1
    ghci-8.2.2
    haskeline-0.7.4.0
    hoopl-3.10.2.2
    hpc-0.6.0.3
    integer-gmp-1.0.1.0
    pretty-1.1.3.3
    process-1.6.1.0
    rts-1.0
    template-haskell-2.12.0.0
    terminfo-0.4.1.0
    time-1.8.0.2
    transformers-0.5.2.0
    unix-2.7.2.2
    xhtml-3000.2.2
```

Output for pacman -Ql xmonad :

```
xmonad /usr/
xmonad /usr/bin/
xmonad /usr/bin/xmonad
xmonad /usr/lib/
xmonad /usr/lib/ghc-8.2.2/
xmonad /usr/lib/ghc-8.2.2/site-local/
xmonad /usr/lib/ghc-8.2.2/site-local/xmonad-0.13/
xmonad /usr/lib/ghc-8.2.2/site-local/xmonad-0.13/Paths_xmonad.dyn_hi
xmonad /usr/lib/ghc-8.2.2/site-local/xmonad-0.13/XMonad.dyn_hi
xmonad /usr/lib/ghc-8.2.2/site-local/xmonad-0.13/XMonad/
xmonad /usr/lib/ghc-8.2.2/site-local/xmonad-0.13/XMonad/Config.dyn_hi
xmonad /usr/lib/ghc-8.2.2/site-local/xmonad-0.13/XMonad/Core.dyn_hi
xmonad /usr/lib/ghc-8.2.2/site-local/xmonad-0.13/XMonad/Layout.dyn_hi
xmonad /usr/lib/ghc-8.2.2/site-local/xmonad-0.13/XMonad/Main.dyn_hi
xmonad /usr/lib/ghc-8.2.2/site-local/xmonad-0.13/XMonad/ManageHook.dyn_hi
xmonad /usr/lib/ghc-8.2.2/site-local/xmonad-0.13/XMonad/Operations.dyn_hi
xmonad /usr/lib/ghc-8.2.2/site-local/xmonad-0.13/XMonad/StackSet.dyn_hi
xmonad /usr/lib/libHSxmonad-0.13-K842KXy8eLK2djQHd55ZyZ-ghc8.2.2.so
xmonad /usr/share/
xmonad /usr/share/doc/
xmonad /usr/share/doc/xmonad/
xmonad /usr/share/doc/xmonad/LICENSE
xmonad /usr/share/haskell/
xmonad /usr/share/haskell/register/
xmonad /usr/share/haskell/register/xmonad.sh
xmonad /usr/share/haskell/unregister/
xmonad /usr/share/haskell/unregister/xmonad.sh
xmonad /usr/share/licenses/
xmonad /usr/share/licenses/xmonad/
xmonad /usr/share/licenses/xmonad/LICENSE
xmonad /usr/share/man/
xmonad /usr/share/man/man1/
xmonad /usr/share/man/man1/xmonad.1.gz
xmonad /usr/share/pixmaps/
xmonad /usr/share/pixmaps/xmonad.svg
xmonad /usr/share/xmonad/
xmonad /usr/share/xmonad/man/
xmonad /usr/share/xmonad/man/xmonad.1
xmonad /usr/share/xmonad/man/xmonad.1.html
xmonad /usr/share/xmonad/man/xmonad.hs
xmonad /usr/share/xsessions/
xmonad /usr/share/xsessions/xmonad.desktop
```

Comment: What are you error messages, how did you install xmonad?

Comment: Weird. This just happened to me a few times when I tried to recompile via my keybinding. After that I tried it from the terminal and it ran fine, and now the keybinding works again.

Comment: I installed xmonad  and xmonad -contrib via pacman. I also tried building xmonad with stack, and providing the absolute path of built xmonad in xsession, which didn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: Related maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390858/xmonad-cant-find-module-xmonad-or-any-other

Comment: @DarthFennec related .. yes. but none of the solutions work.

Comment: How many ghcs do you have and which one is in your PATH? What does `type -a ghc` say?

Comment: @melpomene i have added the output.

Comment: @sidhartharya Then if you installed xmonad with pacman, it's only visible to `/usr/bin/ghc` (the system ghc), not `/usr/local/bin/ghc` (the one you get when you just run `ghc` on the command line).

Comment: @melpomene so should i delete /usr/local/bin/ghc???

Comment: @sidhartharya Why do you have a `/usr/local/bin/ghc` in the first place? You could probably also install XMonad in your local ghc.

Comment: @melpomene i have no idea. beacause stack and cabal install it at home directory. it must be pacman thing, or maybe i tried building from source. Thanks though i ll try your solution.

Comment: Does not look like Xmonad is installed. What is the output of `pacman -Ql xmonad`?

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski added

Answer (score 3):

SLIGHTLY RELATED,

In a fresh install of **UBUNTU 20.10** I had this issue when I installed xmonad through apt with `sudo apt install xmonad`. I think this also installed xmonad-contrib, which is located here [`libghc-xmonad-contrib-dev`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xmonad-contrib), because I already had that when I tried installing it to see if it fixed. What finally fixed it in the end was cabal-installing xmonad and xmonad-contrib with `cabal install xmonad` then `cabal install --lib xmonad-contrib`, alongside with creating a build command in `~/.xmonad/build`.

Content of `~/.xmonad/build`:

```
ghc -package xmonad -package xmonad-contrib --make xmonad.hs -i -ilib -main-is main -fforce-recomp -o xmonad
```

Here is my command history if it is of any help:

```sh
 1912  ghc-pkg list # to check the output, just as in the question
 1913  cabal install xmonad
 1914  xmonad --recompile
 1915  cabal install xmonad-contrib
 1916  cabal install --lib xmonad-contrib # the previous line gave a warning, so I issued a corrected command.
 1917  xmonad --recompile
 1918  ghc -package xmonad ~/.xmonad/monad.hs
 1919  ghc -package xmonad ~/.xmonad/xmonad.hs # the previous line had a typo, so I had to issue the command again.
 1920  xmonad --recompile
 1921  nano .xmonad/build # when I tried the previous command, it said something about creating the following file, so I created it.
 1922  xmonad --recompile
 1923  chmod u+x .xmonad/build # when I tried the previous command, it complained about the file not being executable and recommended those permissions.
 1924  xmonad --recompile # worked!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably some issue with the XMonad package on Arch linux.

As an alternative you could try `pacman -s haskell-cabal` and `cabal install xmonad`.

Comment: I tried cabal install and stack install. I cannot fix the issue still.

Comment: what is the output of `ghc-pkg list`?

Comment: I have added the output of the ghc-pkg list